# Pop out window not working in Internet Explorer

Tags: magento-1.9

I have a link on my website which creates a pop out window in a CMS page. This work perfectly in Chrome, Oprea and safari but on firefox and IE it creates the pop out window with the correct page. but the main page also redirect to a blank age with [object] on it. This is the code im using to creat the pop out window.

```
    <a style="position:fixed; z-index:999999999; top:35%; right:0px;"  href="javascript:window.open('needhelp', 'HELP', 'width=500,height=500');">NEED HELP?</a>
```

I have added an image below of what happens to the main screen on IE and firefox.
[image]

**So my question is how can i create a pop out window without it re-directing the main page?**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Including JavaScript actions directly in the HTML element is a pretty old-fashioned approach. However, you criticize that an action is taken when a user calls an action (i.e. *go to destination given in `href`*). The given destination is the return value of `window.open()`. That is probably what you see now in the browser's main window.

In order to have only the pop-up opened and not forward to the destination address, just append a `return false;` to your snippet.

You will find plenty of `window.open` working examples in Magento's *frontend* and *adminhtml* templates.